# Propagating datum to children on selection data update

Tags: d3.js

As I understand datum is copied to child nodes when appending elements on selection.
I find it strange that updating datum on parent nodes does not propagate new datum to children.

Example with divs as parent nodes and inputs as children:

http://jsfiddle.net/h63t66ux/

My intuition would be to have new data in `__data__` of inputs, not only divs. To get new data inside children I'm using `d3.select(this.parentNode).datum()`

- I wonder if there is better way?
- I'd like to also understand if there is a reason why data isn't propagated to children?
- Is there a chance to add such feature to d3?

Comment: This is well-documented. Use [`.select()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#select) to propagate the data.

Comment: thanks! that seems to work (using `d3.select('#main').selectAll('div').select('input')` instead of `selectAll('input')` - http://jsfiddle.net/h63t66ux/1/ )

Answer (score 1):

as pointed by Lars Kotthoff using `.select()` to propagate the data does the work - updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h63t66ux/1/